# Increase counter in caption with caption.sty

Tags: captions, counters

It seems that `caption.sty` expands the argument of `\caption` twice, which leads to incorrect or at least unexpected values of counters that are increased within the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{caption}
  \newcounter{mycounter}
  \setcounter{mycounter}{0}

  \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
      \caption[]{%
        \stepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter
      }
    \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

I would expect that `\themycounter` would result in `1`, but in this example it's `2` instead. `caption.sty` is quite a big file and I don't find the corresponding macro that expands the content of `\caption` twice. Is there any way to prevent this behavior or a hook that allows resetting the counter after the first expansion? Or do I have to redefine the `\caption` macro to reset the counter to its previous value?

Comment: Why do you print a counter inside a caption?

Comment: Because it counts (and allows labeling and referencing) panels in the figure. As in "(A) Important Data. OVerview of the data (a) and zoom into some region (b). (B) Some more important data, at linear scale (a) and logarithmic scale (b)".

No, the subfigure and subcaption packages are not what i'm looking for.

Furthermore, I simply want to understand what's happening here.

Comment: Put `\stepcounter{mycounter}` inside the figure, but before `\caption`.

Comment: This does not really explain what's happening. Furthermore, I want to use the `\stepcounter` (`\refstepcounter`, to be honest) inside another macro which also prints the labels for panels. If one has to put the definition outside the `\caption` macro, this would be not very handy and close to labeling panels manually.

Comment: I can't explain what's happening.If it has to be done for every caption, you can use `etoolbox`, and write in your preamble `\pretocmd{\caption}{\refstepcpounter{mycounter}}{}{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard latex caption code sets the content twice to see if it can be centred as one line or needs to be set as a paragraph.

Normally the `caption` package does the same but you can use

```
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
```

to turn off this behaviour.

Comment: However, this will make the caption flushleft, I suppose.

Comment: @Bernard well it depends you can specify the paragraph formatting as centred for example.

Comment: Yes, this works (and makes a one-line caption flusehd left). Interestingly, the standard latex `\caption` code seems to handle this differently than `caption.sty`. If you remove the caption package from the example above, the result of `\themycounter` is `1`, not `2`.

Comment: @PatrickHappel the standard code sets it once if it fits in a line (as here) and twice if it does not.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. This, of course, leads to the next question: How to circumvent this without using `caption.sty`? But the LaTeX kernel is much better to read than `caption.sty`, I'll try to find a solution to that myself.